# How to stop jQuery slidetoggle yo-yo?

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I am new to jQuery but this seems like it should work just fine:

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        $("#btn_toggle_transcript").click(
            function()
            {
                $("#transcript_container").slideToggle(1000);
            }       
        );
    }
);
```

...and it does work, but not correctly. ...at least, not as expected...

Am I correct in assuming that the above code would add a click handler to the element with an ID of "btn_toggle_transcript"?  This click handler, then, would respond to the click by either opening the targetted div (...with the id of "transcript_container") if it is closed, or closing it if it is open?

What is currently happening is this:  clicking the button does, indeed, make the div slide open.  BUT, when it is fully open, it IMMEDIATELY - and with no user input - slides closed again.

I have seen a few forum posts suggesting the possible cause is the handler getting added twice.  However, if I comment out the above code, no action is taken when the button is clicked.  So, the handler is not getting added anywhere else...

Can ANYONE please tell me why my div is yo-yoing closed by itself?

The HTML for the button:

```
<div id="tools_button_container">
    <div class="tools_button" id="btn_toggle_transcript"></div>
</div>
```

The HTML for the sliding div (content is set dynamically):

```
<div id="transcript_container">
    <div id="transcript_contents"></div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#transcript_container{
z-index:4;
position:absolute;
width:290px;
max-height:455px;
top:51px;
right:-2px;
background-color:#90B2D8;
padding:20px 10px 10px 10px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
border-left: 1px solid #000;
border-right: 1px solid #000;
display:none;
}

#transcript_contents{
max-height:375px;
overflow:auto;
margin:20px 0px 10px 0px;
background-color:#ffffff;
padding:0px 5px 0px 5px;
}

#btn_toggle_transcript {
background: url('images/transcript.png') no-repeat 0 0;
display:block;
}

#circle_btn_toggle_transcript:hover {
background-position: 0px -50px;
}
```

==========

EDIT:

I did three things that seem to have helped.  Why they worked, I do not know, but they do.

1) Drupal 6.x uses an old version of jQuery (1.2.2).  There is a module to update to 1.3.2.  I replaced the 1.3.2 update files with the 1.7.1 files and now my DOM reports using v1.7.1 of jQuery.

2) & 3) Despite the fact that I only bind to the click event ONCE (verified by removing the binding and having no action invoked on a button click), I decided to try adding a line to remove my "phantom" binding before I add my actual binding.  Based on my reading, I have decided to use the now recommended on() and off() methods to add/remove the bindings.  My ready() function now looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(
function(){
    $("body").off("click", "#btn_toggle_transcript");
    $("body").on("click", "#btn_toggle_transcript",
        function(){
            $("#transcript_container").slideToggle(1000);
        }
    );
}
);
```

Now, my sliding div opens and stays open until I toggle it closed again. Yay!

A big thank you to all who answered/commented.  Your suggestions and guidance helped me get to a solution.

Cheers!

UPDATE:
As I mentioned in one of the comments, this is running inside Drupal.  As also mentioned, if I commented out the single binding, no action was invoked.  My reasoning was that since the removal of ONE binding ceased to invoke the action, then there was no way it was being bound twice...

DUMB!

While I was correct that there was only one block of binding code, I completely forgot that my module was already adding my js file to the page.  Because I need to deploy my content in non-drupal environments as well, I was also manually adding the js file to my page.  ...two inclusions meant two bindings.  ...that's a few days I'll never get back!

Comment: With just the code posted, this works fine http://jsfiddle.net/FSYEv/  there must be something which is not in this question which is causing the problem.

Comment: I was just about to say that all of this is operating inside of Drupal, so there exists the possibility that there IS someting going on in the background that is causing the problem.

I just don't have any idea where to look or how to find out.

Comment: This may sound strange, but does anything change if you put in event.stopPropagation(); ?

Comment: I changed the above ready() function to: `$(document).ready( function() { $("#circle_btn_toggle_transcript").click( function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); $("#circle_transcript_container").slideToggle(1000); } ); } );` ...but nothing changed.

Did I do that right?

Comment: ...and @James ... Thank you for letting me know about jsfiddle.net. Since I'll likely be doing a lot more JS development in the future, that will be a very useful resource. I don't know if the settings changes I made were reflected in the result, but it seems like the jQuery version I am using is 1.3.2. ...at least that's what Firebug's console seems to indicate. I HAVE installed what I thought was jQuery 1.7, but I'm not sure if it's being initialized. ...or if it would make a difference in this situation.

Comment: Try to use newest version of jQuery if possible. You will find newest version [here](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js).

Answer (score 3):

Its case where click is binded two times. See for a possibility where you have done that. eg. in js file and as well as inside script tag in html document.

Also if container is dynamic, you should use live instead of click.

```
$("selector").live("click", function() { /*body*/ })
```

You can try this.

```
$(document).ready(
function(){
    $("body").click( "#btn_toggle_transcript",
        function(){
            if(!$("#transcript_container").hasClass('opened')) {
              $("#transcript_container").slideDown(1000).addClass('opened');
            } else {
              $("#transcript_container").slideUp(1000);
            }
        }
    );
}
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't help.  :(

Comment: As mentioned, I have tried removing the binding above. By commenting out this one binding, the button no longer invokes any action. As such, I'm forced to assume that this is the ONLY binding being done. Am I wrong to assume that if there was a second binding being added somewhere, my removal of this ine should still result in a call to slideToggle()? Also, I read up on the live() method. It appears to be deprecated as of 1.7. It is now recommended to use the on() method to attach event handlers. [http://api.jquery.com/live/](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: Shukriya Pankaj.  Even though your answer didn't directly help, it gave me that one piece of information that DID.  Upvote! :)

Answer (score 2):

*There is a new solution near the end of my answer.*

I've had this same problem numerous times and definitely only had one call to the function.
For some reason every little step of the way the `tween.end` variable would resort to 0. My workaround to this is as follows:

```
$('body').on('click', '.toggle', function() {
    var ul = $(this).next('ul');
    if (!$(ul).hasClass('open')) {
        $(ul).slideDown({
            step: function(now, tween) {
                if (tween.end == 0) {
                    stop();
                }
            },
            complete: function() {
                $(ul).addClass('open');
            }
        });
    } else {
        $(ul).slideUp('', '', function() {
            $(ul).removeClass('open');
        });
    }
});
```

Bit messy, but that's all I could come up with as I couldn't find another call to the function.

**edit**

An old question - with a new solution.

Simply adding stop() before your slideToggle fixes the recurring yo-yo effect.

`$('#element').stop().slideToggle();`

Comment: $('#element').stop().slideToggle(); worked

Answer (score 0):

You wait for the end of the event to add the class.

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $("body").click( "#btn_toggle_transcript",
            function(){
                if(!$("#transcript_container").hasClass('opened')) {
                    $("#transcript_container").slideDown(1000,function(){$(this).addClass('opened')});
                } else {
                    $("#transcript_container").slideUp(1000,function(){$(this).removeClass('opened')});
                }
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Comment: SO is a english only website. Please translate your answer.

Comment: What Zippy said. Right now, I've marked the answer 'recommend deletion' from review. Which would be a shame, because if you translate the first line, this could be a fine answer.